# How to delete a Django model object automatically after 24 hrs

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to django. I want to delete a model object automatically after the specific time.

#### This is my model i want to delete

```py
class CustomerOrder(models.Model):
    order_types = (
        ('dinein','Dinein'),
        ('delivery','Delivery'),
        ('pickup','Pickup')
    )
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantDetail,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    table_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    total_price = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    success = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True,null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='pending',null=True)
    ordered_menu = models.ManyToManyField(OrderedMenu)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    order_type = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='dinein',choices=order_types)
```

the `timestamp` is the saved time of the current object.

is any idea about how to delete a model object automatically after the specific time? (example after 24 hrs).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use [`django-celery-beat`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes) for periodical tasks.
2. Setup a cron job that would run a manage.py command via bash

**Edit:**
After installing and configuring `django-celery-beat` as mentioned in the documentation you create a celery task that would run every 5 minutes par example:

```
import datetime
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from django.utils import timezone

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='*/5'))
def delete_old_orders():
    d = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    #get expired orders
    orders = CustomerOrder.objects.filter(timestamp__lt=d)
    #delete them
    orders.delete()
```

Comment: could you give me a example program in `django-celery-beat` ?

Comment: @Vaitheeswaran I edit the answer

Comment: Setting up celery on your project can be really difficult if you are alone and haven't done it before. Setting up a lambda function on AWS to poll your database and delete expired orders might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your database server to do the job for you, many database servers will allow you to run queries at scheduled interval.

The exact way to do this will depend on your database server. In Mysql/MariaDb you could use the following:

```sql
CREATE EVENT delete_expired_orders
          ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
          STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
          DO
            DELETE FROM djangoapp_customerorder
            WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) + 86400 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

Note:

- You'll have to change the table name `djangoapp_customerorder` to the correct name.
- `86400` is the number of seconds in one day. What I do instead is have an expiry field in my model, so I just need to use `WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expiry) < UNIT_TIMESTAMP()` without having to add `86400`.

To get this deployed to your various environment, you can add it to your Django migrations by creating a new migration, and adding the SQL code in it like so:

```py
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [("djangoapp", "0001_initial")]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql="""
                CREATE EVENT delete_expired_orders
                ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
               STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
               DO
                   DELETE FROM djangoapp_customerorder
                   WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) + 86400 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
                """,
            reverse_sql="""
                DROP EVENT delete_expired_orders
            """,
        ),
    ]
```

Again you'll need to change `thedjangoapp`, `djangoapp_customerorder` and `0001_initial` as appropriate.

You may need to tweak this further for your environment, but the approach works as I'm using it.